# Different App name to be displayed in iTunes store

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

I have an apple app ready for sale in app store with the app name as    "product master".

I would like to add the string Oz to the app name as "Oz product master". Since the new name is too long, on the phone when installed, the app name is not shown fully below the app icon, it is displayed as "Oz pr.."

Is there a way to keep the app displayed as "product master" below the icon on iPhone and in the iTunes store, have the app displayed as "Oz product master"?

I have tried playing with fields "bundle identifier", "bundle display name" and "product name" but none of this is helping to have a different name displayed on iTunes store alone.

Can someone please advice how I achieve having different name on iTunes store only.

Answer (score 2):

The Product Name is what appears in your iphone only. The name in App Store is displayed following what you enter in appname in iTunesConnect.

Name in iTunes Store can be set as in the following image example:
[image]

See the red rectangle. Here you can have a long name that will appear in
iTunes Store.

Comment: Is there a way to change the display name on iTunes connect? I have tried uploading a newer version of the app but i don't see field/option to update the app name. so I am assuming that it is using one of the attributes from Info.plist as iTunes display name.

Comment: @dacscan3669 I edited my answer. Pls check the image

Answer (score 1):

The app name on `iTunes` store has no effect on the app name displayed on the phone whatsoever. The app name to be displayed on the phone is the name of your `Xcode` project. 
This means that you need to change the name of your `Xcode` project to whatever you want to be displayed on the phone and set the `iTunes` display name in `iTunes connect`

Comment: Is there a way to change the display name on iTunes connect? I have tried uploading a newer version of the app but i don't see field/option to update the app name. so I am assuming that it is using one of the attributes from Info.plist as iTunes display name.

Comment: The name on iTunes connect is chosen when you create an App instance. If you have chosen a wrong name, you will have to create a new instance.